# Hadoop: How to move HDFS files in one directory to another directory?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I have an HDFS soure directory, and a destination archive directory in HDFS.
At the beginning of every run of my job, I need to move (or copy, then delete) all the part files present in my **Source** directory to my **Archive** directory.

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate();
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());
String hdfsSrcDir = "hdfs://clusterName/my/source";
String archiveDir = "hdfs://clusterName/my/archive";
try{
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new URI(hdfsSrcDir ),jsc.hadoopConfiguration());
}
```

I don't know how to proceed further. Presently my `fs` object has reference to only my **source** directory.
Creating an `fs2` with **archive** location won't help I believe.

I have found out about `FileSystem.rename()`, but that takes filenames as parameters. I need to move `/my/source/*` to `/my/archive/`.

Answer (score 1):

Check if this will works for you,

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration(); 
configuration.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://xyz:1234"); 
FileSystem filesystem = FileSystem.get(configuration); 
FileUtil.copy(filesystem, new Path("src/path"), 
              filesystem, new Path("dst/path"), false, configuration); 
filesystem.delete(new Path("src/path"), true);
```

Comment: does the destination path has to be a **directory** or a **file** ? Currently I am providing the destination path as a directory with `777` permission, but it is showing me permission denied exception: `Permission denied: user=aiman, access=WRITE, inode="/xyz/my/archive":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x`.  Hadoop ls command shows: `drwxrwxrwx   - aiman hdfs          0 2018-05-18 20:00 /my/archive`.

Comment: @Aiman - I guess, destination path should be directory, seems like error is due to permission issue, that need to figure out, but in meanwhile you can try to copy file in your user hdfs directory for testing.